# pandas - remove duplicates, count items, from columns with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove duplicates per row then create a column with the count of in each row for that user.

Current DataFrame

```
    handle            tweet

0   CaptainNormal     [@WayneDupreeShow, #climatechange, @Wsow]
1   Cebel6            [@NWAJimmy, @NWAJimmy, @gaystoner821]
2   davidjwalling     [#infosec, #Intel, #ACM, #IEEE]
3   nolaguy_phd       [@gaystoner821]
```

Desired DataFrame

```
    handle            tweet                                        count

0   CaptainNormal     [@WayneDupreeShow, #climatechange, @Wsow]    3
1   Cebel6            [@NWAJimmy, @gaystoner821]                   2
2   davidjwalling     [#infosec, #Intel, #ACM, #IEEE]              4
3   nolaguy_phd       [@gaystoner821]                              1
```

I've tried something like

```
df.tweet.apply(tuple).value_counts()
```

but returns 1 for everything.

Comment: What is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'tweet']))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values are `string`s, first convert:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'tweet']))
<class 'str'>

import ast
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Alternative:

```
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',\s+')
```

And then convert to `set`s and get length:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'tweet']))
<class 'list'>

df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
df['count'] = df['tweet'].str.len()
print (df)
          handle                                      tweet  count
0  CaptainNormal  [#climatechange, @Wsow, @WayneDupreeShow]      3
1         Cebel6                 [@NWAJimmy, @gaystoner821]      2
2  davidjwalling            [#ACM, #IEEE, #infosec, #Intel]      4
3    nolaguy_phd                            [@gaystoner821]      1
```

Comment: Yeah this worked. Does set(x) convert the tweet column to a set which has no unique values then you used list() to return it to a list?

Also why does str.len() return the amount of values in list?

Thanks by the way.

Comment: @qrs - str.len return lengths of all iterable, so working nice with strings, tuples, lists, sets ;)

Comment: @qrs - Glad can help!